# Ionic 3 How to display toast on modal?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Hello I have uncommon structure of creating activity. First `OverviewPage` user can open the modal, which after selecting one activity from list pushes to desired `activityPage` - activity creation page.

Once user leaves that page, submit new activity I use nav methods in that order

```js
this.navCtrl.getPrevious().data.toastMessage = 'Added activity successfully';
this.navCtrl.pop();
```

After adding new activity it returns to `OverviewPage` with modal opened, unfortunatelly it doesn't reload that page so I cannot detect in ionViewWillEnter if I can show that popover.

```js
if(this.navParams.data.toastMessage) {
 this.presentToast(this.navParams.data.toastMessage)
}
```

How can I change code to display that toastMessage in modal after creating new activity ? Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to present a toast inside of a modal? I just want to understand what exactly you're wanting.

Comment: It works like this on `DailyOverViewPage` you can open the modal with links to various activities - each activity leads to specific page. Once you create an activity it pops to previous page where the modal is still open for user to create another one if he wants to do so. It's not well designed to be fair. However I've managed to deal with it different way, I've abandoned idea of sending the `navParams` to the modal and stick with displaying the toast after activity creation on that activity page - so it stays on screen long enough to show up even on that modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was pretty simple, don't know if its recommended or not, but I left the `presentModal` functions inside of each activity and removed that part:

`this.navCtrl.getPrevious().data.toastMessage = 'Added activity successfully';`

So right now the last lines of activity creation are display toast and pop navigation stack and surprisingly it works great.

```
this.appFunctionCtrl.presentSuccessToast('Added activity successfully', 1500);
this.navCtrl.pop();
```